# jasmine mock-ajax with JSON

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

I have tried to mock/stub my ajax call, but it looks like it only works with text. When I tried to set response with object then my done callback is not called:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/some_url/1').andReturn({
  //"responseText": response ,
 "response": response,
  "status": 200
});
```

, but when I set responseText with object then it is called, but the responseJSON is not set, when debug response in FF

```
responseJSON undefined
status 200
statusText "success"
```

Am I doing something wrong or it is an issue?

I am using Jasmine 2.1.3 and latest version of jasmine-ajax (honestly I cannot figure it out where I can find version I am using...;-), I've just downloaded mock-ajax.js from link in documentation in github)

UPDATE:
It was my bad. I have tried to push plain `Object`, when used `JSON.stringify` and pass the result to "responseText" it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the "response" attribute, you need to use either "responseText" or "responseJSON", depending upon your stubbed data's type.

If your response is already parsed JSON (i.e., an actual JSON object and not a string), then use "responseJSON".

Comment: Hi thanks for response, I tried "responseJSON" but it is the same. I have looked into mock-ajax.js and there is nothing like that... I've just realized that I have been passing plain `Object`, when I passed result of `JSON.stringify` to "responseText" it works as expected. Anyway thanks for your help:-)