# How to mock ajax call to Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

Here is my code:

```
function sendRequestData(url, urlParameters) {
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    },
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(urlParameters),
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        successCallBack(data)
    },
    error : function(data, status, errorThrown) {
        failCallBack(data, status, errorThrown)
    }
});
```

I want to mock and test this ajax call. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine 2.0 how to handle ajax requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245991/jasmine-2-0-how-to-handle-ajax-requests)

Comment: The jasmine.Ajax.install() is not showing up. I have added the dependency too. Also, do I call this method before or after I load the fixture?

Comment: @Jasmine it is a separate plugin. You need to [install it here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

If your test are hard to test, this means you are doing something wrong.

In your specific case, you need follow [Dependency Inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (think Dependency Injection) and **inject your requirements** into your function. Basically, you need to pass in all the dependencies including `$`, `successCallback` and `failCallback`. This would let you mock your ajax calls with Jasmine's [`spyOn()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) method and then check for correct function calls.

```
function sendRequestData(url, urlParameters, $, successCallBack, failCallBack) {
  $.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    },
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(urlParameters),
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        successCallBack(data)
    },
    error : function(data, status, errorThrown) {
        failCallBack(data, status, errorThrown)
    }
  });
}
```

Your tests might look like this. I have not checked it, but you get an idea of what I mean.

```
describe("sendRequestData() does correct ajax calls", function() {
  var $ok, $error, successCallback, failCallback = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    // You can create a spy object using this syntax
    $ok = jasmine.createSpyObj('$', ['ajax']);

    // Or define it yourself like so
    $ok = {
      ajax: function(value) {
        successCallback();
      }
    };

    $error = {
      ajax: function(value) {
        failCallback();
      }
    };

    spyOn($, 'ajax');
    spyOn(successCallback);
    spyOn(failCallback);
  });

  it("calls successCallback on success", function() {
    sendRequestData('url', {}, $ok, successCallback, failCallback);
    expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(successCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(failCallbackCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("calls failCallback on failure", function() {
    sendRequestData('url', {}, $error, successCallback, failCallback);
    expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(successCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(failCallbackCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Or simply use [jasmine-ajax](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html) plugin to mock your ajax calls.

Comment: Is there any method I can use when using jasmine-ajax. I am new to this. Thank you very much

Comment: Sure, the official docs have great examples [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html#section-Basic_Usage_Across_An_Entire_Suite).

Comment: How can I mock my ajaxcall using the Jasmine-ajax plugin?

Comment: Click here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html#section-Basic_Usage_Across_An_Entire_Suite

Comment: Can I call the function that uses ajax using this? Will this cover my function?

Comment: Hmm... I think if you want to write tests using Jasmine, then you should learn how to use it first. Youtube has many videos. I think you should learn it first and if you have any question then ask them here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on legacy code and cannot change the JS code maybe you can try as below

JS file

```
$.ajax({
  async      : true,
  type       : "POST",
  data       : requestPayload,
  url        : APIURL,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success    : function (response) {
    /* -- some code here --*/
  },
  error      : function (errorResponse) {
    /* -- some code here --*/
  }
});
```

SPEC file

```
it("check api call", function () { 
 var testResponse = {
    'status'    : 'ok',
    'errorCode' : '',
    'message'   : 'this is a mock response'
  };
/*...*/
  spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(e) {
  return e.success(testResponse);
    // for failure case 
    //return e.error({
    //  'status'    : 'not_ok',
    //  'errorCode' : 'Unauthorized'
    //});
  });
  form.submit();  
  });
```

You can also call the e.success and
**return $.Deferred().resolve(testData).promise();** from what I have understood in other examples.
[Mocking jQuery ajax calls with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851692/mocking-jquery-ajax-calls-with-jasmine)

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (e) {
  e.success(testData)
  return $.Deferred().resolve(testData).promise();
});
```