# Unit tesing an api call using jasmine

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js, web-api-testing

I am writing unit tests for my website at work and I cant seem to figure out how to test an api call.

Lets say I want to test an api call in one of my Vue components

```
  api.ajax("users")
.done((response) => {
  stores.usersStore.init(response)
})
```

**usersStore.js**

```
 let usersStore = {

  store: {
    users: []
  },

  get() {
    return this.store
  },

  set(key, value) {
    if (key) {
      this.users[key] = value
    } else {
      console.error("Key required")
    }
  },

  init(initObject) {
    this.store.users = initObject
  }


}

export default usersStore;
```

So the api call basically just initializes the array of users. How do I test something like this in jasmine? I tried spies, and mocking.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Edit --> The test I am attempting to write

```
  describe(" Tests", function() {

  var us;

    beforeEach(function() {

      us = new usersStore()
       us.store.users.push("Anand Dharne")
    });

    describe("when retrieved by name", function() {
      var u;

      beforeEach(function(done) {
        u = us.init(response, {
          success: function () {
            done();
          }
        });
      });

      it("api call", function() {
        expect(u.store.users).toEqual("Anand Dharne");
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please show your attempts on testing this with "spies, and mocking" so the community can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I am trying to do something like this check the new edit

Answer (score 0):

- You may spy on the ajax object.
- Since I'm not completely familiar with vue.js I'd like to share a simple implementation using plain javascript, jQuery & jasmine . [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/31/)

  ```
  var usersStore = {
   store: {
      users: []
    },
    get: function() {
      return this.store;
    },
    set: function(key, value) {
      if (key) {
        this.store[key] = value;
      } else {
        console.error("Key required");
      }
    },
    init: function(initObject) {
      this.store.users = initObject;
    }
  };

  var api = {
    serviceCall: () => {
      $.ajax('').done((data) => {
        usersStore.init(data);
      });
    }
  };

  describe('test api call', () => {
    it('ajax success', () => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
      var userObj = [{
        'name': 'StackOverflow'
      }];
      spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake((e) => {
        return $.Deferred().resolve(userObj).promise();
      });
      api.serviceCall();
      expect(usersStore.get().users[0].name).toEqual('StackOverflow');
    });
  });
  ```

Points to Note:

- The code `this.users[key] = value` from your set method may not be valid as `users` is not available directly, its a sub-object of `store`
- You need to use a custom $Deferred() object that returns a promise which could either be resolved/rejected
- I've not used arrow functions for the methods of object as they need a this reference. More about [arrow function here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- Also to explore other options of mocking ajax calls, I'd suggest you to start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851692/mocking-jquery-ajax-calls-with-jasmine/42007610)